# Copy data from Vertica to Redis using ETL tool (Datasatge 11.7) or any other method

Tags: database, redis, etl, vertica, datastage

I need to know that how i can copy data from **vertica** to **redis** DB after transforming in ETL job and then move data to REDIS DB using ETL tool datatstage

The purpose of this activity is to load data from vertica db to Redis.

Is there any way or method to do this activity.

Comment: Use a DataStage straight-move job: Create ODBC connections in DataStage for Vertica and Redis, import source table and target table definition, (hopefully same structure), create straight-move mapping in DataStage - and execute ...

Comment: can you please tell me how i can create ODBC in system dsn connection with redis.

Comment: I heard you can connect to Redis using ODBC. If it is possible, then the Redis documentation will have a chapter on where to get theIr ODBC driver, and how to install it on Linux and Windows, and how to set up an ODBC Data Source. I'd look for it there

Comment: Dear i have connect redis with datastage using ODBC but i am unable to send commands to redis through datastage. Can you help me out that how i can insert data with ODBC